# Match the extensions stored in database to currently uploaded file extensions

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a table called `video_type` where i store video files in extensions like `avi,mp4,3gp` and i have a php file to upload form ,where i will upload only video files so for that i should check the file uploaded must match the extensions stored in a table `video_type` ,if the file uploaded is not a video file then it should alert some message to upload only video files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Incognito The question is clear. That he want to upload video files but the files extensions must be given into his database.

Comment: I commented because it's not clear where OP is stuck! I understand what he explained about the table storing the allowed extensions, and the part where an error message should come. But, he has to tell us what part after this he needs help in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to fetch extension of uploaded file.

```
$path = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

and than you can fetch records of extension stored in DB which is any array.

```
$allowed_extensions = array('avi','mp4','3gp');
```

Now use php in_array() function to validate image extension.

```
if (in_array($ext, $allowed_extensions)) {
 echo "A valid file"
}else{
 echo "Invalid file";
}
```